# Communication between android apps on same device

Tags: android, android-intent, aidl

I am building an app that does specific calculations base on data it fetches from the internet, let's call those calculations "final data". The final data must be available (read and write) for other apps on the same device (3rd party apps).
So the plan is to create an Android library/module and distribute it. 
Once a 3rd party app developer adds this library to his app, his app must be able to read/write the "final data" that my app holds (if my app is installed) and to execute some methods on my app (`recalculateStuff()`).

I ran into a wall deciding what is the best way of implementing the said library, and here are the options I've tried/looked into:

1. AIDL
2. Bound services
3. Intents
4. Custom local tcp server/client, or http server/client

One important thing is that I want to be able to know which 3rd party app is trying to modify a value (as the user will be able to allow/block specific apps from reading/writing the final data), and for this, solution number 3 and 4 will not be suitable (please correct me because i am often wrong), and I couldn't find a way to verify the "requester package name" in 1 and 2.

Also someone mentioned that AIDL will not work between apps that are signed with different keys, is that true (couldn't find anything in Android developer documentation, and haven't tested yet)?

My questions are: Are there any other better way of doing this (communication and identification)? if yes, which? if no which one of the 4 considered-solutions fits best?
Thank you

Comment: To communicate with another app you can use the Shared Preferencies. See https://medium.com/@kuls.droid/access-shared-preference-data-from-one-application-to-another-application-in-android-863af845de4c

Comment: `solution number 3 and 4 will not be suitable ` That is suitable as you can let them login first.

Comment: You can add a ContentProvider to your app to serve your data.

Comment: @blackapps I'm not sure how 3 can be suitable. but with 4, anyone that knows the protocol can trick the main app into believing the requests are coming from another app (for example rouge app sending a DELETE ALL request and identifies as "good app" while doing so)

Comment: @daniel.jbatiz thanks for you comment, Shared Preferencies will now allow 3rd party apps to execute some functions as well. forgot to mention that

Comment: Sorry, i ment solution 4. And use login.